# How to make footable work in a table that's being populated with JS from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like this:

```
<table id="thatTable" class="table toggle-circle">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>FieldA</th>
    <th data-hide="all">FieldB</th>
    <th data-hide="all">FieldC</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
          <div class="text-right">
              <ul class="pagination"></ul>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Then a JS like this:

```
var fillThatTable = function (list) {
    $.each(list, function (index, item) {
        $('#thatTable tbody').append($('<tr>')
            .append($('<td>').text(item.ID))
            .append($('<td>').text(item.FieldA))
            .append($('<td>').text(item.FieldB))
            .append($('<td>').text(item.FieldC))
            )
        );
    });
};
```

Everything works fine, the table gets the data and shows it all. Problem comes when I want to set `footable()` to that table, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    fillThatTable();
    $('#thatTable').footable();
});
```

And instead of getting something beautiful, I just receive an average filtered table, almost like I didn't put that `$('#thatTable').footable()`. I checked the JS are imported, they are. Is it maybe because the table doesn't have anything in the `tbody`? What am I missing?

Dream:
[image: Something like this]

Reality:
[image: Instead of this]

Comment: Your code looks like working, and `footable()` is getting applied. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/830553/

Comment: Hm, isn't working, sure it does for you? Send a capture please.

Comment: In that jsfiddle, just remove the line where footable is getting applied, i.e. `$('#thatTable').footable()` . See the table, and then add the line again and see the difference it table.

Comment: Yeah it works there but not on my code, and console doesn't display any error related to that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated PM's fiddle to make an easier use of FooTable: http://jsfiddle.net/0pb4x7h6/1

If your html changes to this:

```
<table id="thatTable" class="table toggle-circle">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-name="ID">ID</th>
    <th data-name="FieldA">FieldA</th>
    <th data-name="FieldB" data-breakpoints="all">FieldB</th>
    <th data-name="FieldC" data-breakpoints="all">FieldC</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
          <div class="text-right">
              <ul class="pagination"></ul>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Then you can simplify your script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = [
    {"ID":"1","FieldA":"A1","FieldB":"B1","FieldC":"C1"},
    {"ID":"2","FieldA":"A2","FieldB":"B2","FieldC":"C2"},
    {"ID":"3","FieldA":"A3","FieldB":"B3","FieldC":"C3"}
    ];

    // No need for this
    //fillThatTable();
    $('#thatTable').footable({
        rows: list
    });
});
```